# Setting appropiate unix permissions for shared FTP access on WordPress directory

Tags: permissions, apache-httpd, sftp, vsftpd

I have two user accounts on my Ubuntu server, one is part of the sudo group and the other is a standard user. For demonstration purposes I will use the following user names:

- admin_user (sudo group privileges)
- standard_user (no admin
  privileges)

I am setting up my server to host WordPress which is located at `/var/www/example.com`. I have also setup VSFTPD and SFTP to allow FTP access to the server, and each user is currently chrooted to their home directory. After following this guide [here](https://wordpress.org/support/article/changing-file-permissions/), WordPress recommends having a separate account for FTP access and another one for running the server process itself (NGINX or Apache).

> "Typically, all files should be owned by your user (ftp) account on
> your web server, and should be writable by that account. On shared
> hosts, files should never be owned by the webserver process itself
> (sometimes this is www, or apache, or nobody user). Any file that
> needs write access from WordPress should be owned or group-owned by
> the user account used by WordPress (which may be different than the
> server account). For example, you may have a user account that lets
> you FTP files back and forth to your server, but your server itself
> may run using a separate user, in a separate usergroup, such as
> dhapache or nobody. If WordPress is running as the FTP account, that
> account needs to have write access, i.e., be the owner of the files,
> or belong to a group that has write access. In the latter case, that
> would mean permissions are set more permissively than default (for
> example, 775 rather than 755 for folders, and 664 instead of 644)."

By running the following command `sudo apachectl -S` I can see that Apache2 is running as

```
User: name="www-data" id=33
Group: name="www-data" id=33
```

`sudo ps -aux | egrep apache2 '(httpd|apache2|apache)'` confirms this too.

With that in mind, I have run the following command to change the owner and group of the web root directory

```
sudo chown -R admin_user:www-data /var/www/example.com
```

On WordPress' hardening guide 'Changing file permissions' found [here](https://wordpress.org/support/article/hardening-wordpress/#changing-file-permissions) I have run the following commands

```
find /var/www/example.com/ -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
find /var/www/example.com/ -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

Whilst logged in as an admin via FTP/SFTP I can delete, make new files and change permissions. Owners of filed/directories are the only ones that can change the permissions; that's just how Unix permissions work. Now this works perfectly fine in normal cases with only one user managing the server via FTP. However, I would like the standard user to be able to delete and write files/directories in the web root too. Would it be safe to assume adding the standard_user to the www-data group (the same group that the apache2 process runs under) and give a more open set permissions on the group will be safe and sufficient?

```
sudo usermod -a -G www-data standard_user
find /var/www/example.com/ -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;
find /var/www/example.com/ -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;
```

I then set the permissions on specific files

```
sudo chmod 440 /var/www/example.com/wp-config.php
sudo chmod 664 /var/www/example.com/.htaccess
```

As a side question, would leaving the owner of the web root directory set to the `root` user account, and adding the additional `admin_user` account to `www-data` group alongside the `standard_user` be considered as safe?

```
sudo usermod -a -G www-data admin_user
sudo chown -R root:www-data /var/www/example.com
```

**UPDATE 1**

With the permissions set above I have tried to upload a WordPress theme via the web browser and immediately WordPress was asking for FTP access which indicates a permission issue. I've done some reading on the internet and it seems some guides tell you to set the owner and group to `www-data` and insert `define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');` into the `wp-config.php` file as shown in [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-wordpress-on-ubuntu-20-04-with-a-lamp-stack) guide for example. However, is this considered safe?

Comment: You keep saying "_FTP/SFTP_". They are totally different protocols. Do you mean FTP, or SFTP, or both, or did you really mean FTP/S? (What do you think you mean by SFTP anyway?)

Comment: I am using both. VSFTPD handles FTPS (implicit) and SSH handles SFTP.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation